# SELECT rows NOT ending in a specific character

Tags: mysql

I have a table of questions. I need to find rows which have '?' in the question text because of bad character encoding/collation. I need to find all the rows which have '?' but also need to ignore the question marks at the end of the questions. I tried this query but I still get rows with questions marks at end of the question

```
SELECT * 
FROM `kc_questions` 
WHERE `question` LIKE "%?%" /* WHICH CONTAINS '?' */
AND `question` NOT LIKE "%?"  /* DOES NOT END WITH '?' */
```

EDIT: phpmyadmin actually tells me there is something wrong with the query:
[image]

The query however runs successfully returning rows which end with'?'.

Comment: From what you asked in the original question and some comments, it seems you type some special characters. Like holding down shift when typing space, this creates special characters not allowed in the sql syntax

Comment: Yes, characters from other languages like Greek alphabets are expected to be entered. But later I have changed the charset and collation to accept them. The problem was with already existing data where special characters are displayed as '?'. So I wanted to filter them and correct them manually.

Comment: I meant the space in your SQL syntax "`…'question' NOT…`" might not be a simple space but a special character. Which would explain why your sql syntax is wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the sample data I tried the following demo and it works as expected.

SQL:

```
create table kc_questions(question varchar(200));
insert into kc_questions values
('Ex1. ?-particles are harmul for human body. Select True or False.'),
('Ex2. What is your name?');

SELECT question FROM kc_questions;
SELECT * 
FROM `kc_questions` 
WHERE `question` LIKE "%?%" 
AND `question` NOT LIKE "%?";
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT question FROM kc_questions;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| question                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ex1. ?-particles are harmul for human body. Select True or False. |
| Ex2. What is your name?                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM `kc_questions`
    -> WHERE `question` LIKE "%?%"
    -> AND `question` NOT LIKE "%?";
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| question                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ex1. ?-particles are harmul for human body. Select True or False. |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.8-rc  |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Although when i just do "%?%" I get rows containin both real ? and bad character.

Comment: @eNeMetcH Then try what you can get using following stmt: SELECT * FROM `kc_questions` WHERE `question` LIKE "%?"

Comment: That will give me all the rows which has an ending "?". Lets forget bad characters, How do I fetch rows which contain "?" but not at the end

Comment: @eNeMetcH Pls provide two sample of your strings, with and without ? at the end. I tried by myself, it works fine.

Comment: Ex1. ?-particles are harmul for human body. Select True or False.
Ex2. What is your name?

I want to select values like Ex 1 and ignore values like Ex2 (Check Question EDIT)

Comment: @eNeMetcH I tried with your sample strings. It works fine for me. Pls check the update post.

Comment: Thanks! But could you tell me why phpmyadmin says it does not recognise NOT

Comment: Not sure about that. Never used phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression

```
SELECT * 
FROM `kc_questions` 
WHERE `question` REGEXP '.*\?.+$'
```

Basicly you search for questions which contains '?' with at least one character after the '?'

Comment: It says Unrecognized keyword REGEXP! Is something wrong with my phpmyad :/min?

Comment: Could be that it is not enabled. But with phpmyadmin you might need to double escape certain charaters, sou you might need to write '.*\\?.+$'